# Android App is loading the View through Webview URL but not loading the audio that URL has in the background

Tags: php, android, html, laravel, android-studio

I have an Android App loading the view through Webview Url. The Url has a background audio in it. The Url is loading properly but not playing the audio.

This is my HTML Code where i am playing the audio in html.

```
@if($booking->order_status == "Pending")
    <audio autoplay>
         <source src="notification/tune.mp3">
    </audio>
@endif
```

And javascript part to run this audio.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var context = new AudioContext();
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me what i need to add in my android app code to also run the audio in the background when loading the URL with Webview.

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

add this setting to webview object

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)
```